# Session Issues Symfony 3.4: Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a Symfony 3.4 site locally using Wamp64.  Session management is the default Symfony 3.4 setup (in files).  The only thing my code specifically adds  to session storage is a single variable, an integer.

However, I can replicate an issue after browsing through a few pages that I get the error:

```
Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed
```

It happens only when leaving certain pages (and they seem to be pages with relatively large number of form fields, including 4 or 5 EntityType fields).  It acts as if the session file is getting too large (although I have found no evidence that there is a size limit, the file is about 50kB) or is corrupted by the data in the forms.   I found threads indicating that this can be caused by storing unusual characters but I'm not doing anything unusual with the forms or entitities with regards to character sets.

Initially, I had been storing a complete entity in the session.  Research showed that might be the issue so refactored things to store only the entity's ID.  No change.  I  found threads here blaming the issue on garbage collection but no change I made there made any difference.  I  am not experiencing this issue on the deployment server, at least not yet.

The text of the error message seems to be coming from PHP itself (the string is not in the symfony script files).

Any ideas?   Or suggestions for debugging?

Update: I found that the issue is indeed triggering by saving a complex entity to the Session (searching failed to find it for some reason).    So nevermind.  I just need to find another way to go about it.

Comment: Suggestions: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/16493/weird-session-error-failed-to-decode-session-object-session-has- and http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/90909/failed-to-decode-session-object-session-has-been-destroyed-in-class-ostsession-php

Comment: are you using fosuserbundle ? or show me your config.yml, maybe should be util !